# Golang postgres проверить если запрос не вернул записей

Tags: postgresql, golang, null

Есть такой код:

```
func ModelLoginAuth(id, pwd string) ([]*MedReg) { //Cписок мед регистраторов
    rows := db.Select(`SELECT fam, left(name,1), left(lastname, 1)
    FROM j_catalog_vrach
    WHERE name_the_post = 'Регистратор' AND id = $1 AND pwd = $2
    ORDER BY id DESC`, utils.NullableInt(id), utils.NullableString(pwd))
    defer rows.Close()
    bks := make([]*MedReg, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        bk := new(MedReg)
        var famStr sql.NullString
        var nameStr sql.NullString
        var lastname sql.NullString

        rows.Scan(&famStr, &nameStr, &lastname)
        bk.Fam = famStr.String
        bk.Name = nameStr.String
        bk.LastName = lastname.String
        bks = append(bks, bk)
    }
    return bks

}
```

например такой запрос к Select(query)

```
SELECT fam, left(name,1), left(lastname, 1)
 FROM j_catalog_vrach
 WHERE name_the_post = 'Регистратор' AND id = $1 AND pwd = $2
```

который не нашел записей в базе по данным из запроса, как проверить на "nil" возвращаемый результат? 
К примеру:

if bks == nil /////

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
if len(bks) == 0
```

или так:

```
func LoginAuth(r *http.Request, rnd render.Render)  {
    r.ParseForm()
    bks := models.ModelLoginAuth(r.FormValue("id"), r.FormValue("pwd"))
    if bks[0].Count == "1" {
        rnd.Redirect("take_to_repair", 200)
    } else {
        rnd.HTML(403, "login", nil)
    }


}

func ModelLoginAuth(id, pwd string) ([]*MedReg) { //Cписок мед регистраторов
    rows := db.Select(`SELECT count(*)
    FROM j_catalog_vrach
    WHERE name_the_post = 'Регистратор' AND id = $1 AND pwd = $2
    `, utils.NullableInt(id), utils.NullableString(pwd))
    defer rows.Close()
    bks := make([]*MedReg, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        bk := new(MedReg)
        var countStr sql.NullString
        rows.Scan(&countStr)
        bk.Count = countStr.String
        bks = append(bks, bk)
    }
    return bks

}
```